# Why is a join from a remote table so slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, remote-server

Imagine that I have this query:

```
SELECT L.id, L.name, R.phone
FROM users L
JOIN [remoteServer].[dbo].[phoneNumbers] R ON R.fk_id=L.id
WHERE L.id=12345
```

In SQL Server 2008, if I show the execution plan, I see that my local SQL server queries the whole remote table (`SELECT id, phone FROM [remoteServer].[dbo].[phoneNumbers]`) then applies the filter locally.

Why doesn't it queries the filtered remote table (`SELECT id, phone FROM [remoteServer].[dbo].[phoneNumbers] WHERE id=12345`) because only the records matching `id` will be used?

I guess my question is: how can I make this happen since SQL Server doesn't do this by default?

Comment: Maybe you can explore `join hints`. Never used it but it may help. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx

Comment: `REMOTE` hint should do the job.

Comment: @a1ex07 you're right. I just tried it here and that's the way to go.

Comment: Why aren't you using aliasing and prefixing any of your columns? I have no idea which columns come from which table. It's possibly you can use `EXISTS` or a subquery or a `REMOTE` hint (I wrote a tip about those here, but found that in my test cases it didn't help: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2765/revisit-your-use-of-the-sql-server-remote-join-hint/). Right now I can't make any suggestions because your code is neither complete nor self-documenting.

Comment: I added columns prefix to make the code clearer. L is the Local table, R is the Remote table.

Comment: From what I understand, REMOTE just reverse the situation: it sends the local table to the remote server and does the join on the remote server. It's useful if the local table is smaller than the remote table but it won't work for all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My observations about linked servers, is that when you use this syntax

```
server.database.schema.table
```

The entire contents of that table are retrieved.  Any filtering is done afterwards.

The solution is to use openquery.

Answer (score 0):

The local instance has no clue about the external object's structure.  It's like reaching in to a black box and asking you to retrieve all the "Smith's" from a table of people.  You wouldn't know where to begin, so you pull it all out first so you can review the entire table.

Comment: I'm joining on column R.fk_id=L.id and the filter is L.id=12345. Maybe I'm missing something but it seems to me that it should be smart enough to figure out that the remote query should filter using R.fk_id=12345